# How to change the height of Upload.Dragger in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd-3.22.0 and react 16.3.2. I want to set the height of `Upload.Dragger` to `45px`.

I have tried setting Dragger height by putting `style={{height:"45px"}}` in the dragger. I have also tried wrapping the dragger in a div and provided height to the div but it didn't work.

```html
<Upload.Dragger style={{height:'45px'}}>
     <p className="ant-upload-text">Browse or drag file</p>
</Upload.Dragger>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be providing height to the content enclosed by the `Dragger` as it will take the height of the contents in it.

```
<Upload.Dragger>
    <p className="ant-upload-text" style={{height: "85px"}}>Browse or drag file</p>
</Upload.Dragger>
```

Wrapping the dragger won't work as you aren't setting the height of the dragger component but enclosing it in another div of certain height.

Comment: @AnushkaSubedi I've tried it in codesandbox and it's working. https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sinoussi-rtdh0

Comment: Thank you so much for the code sandbox example. Exactly what I am looking for but not sure why is the height of the dragger still unaffected on mine. Will update soon!!

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper is

```js
const UploadWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
`;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding some explanation on how and why it solves it will improve the quality of your answer